# Haskell composition with two parameters

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, function-composition

I'm trying to understand functional programming through Haskell and I'm having so much trouble dealing with function composition.

Actually I have these two functions :

```
add:: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
add x y =  x + y

sub:: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
sub x y =  x - y
```

I want to be able to compose them. It doesn't make any sense okay, but it's for a learning aim.

**What I've tried :**

```
foo:: (Integer -> Integer) -> (Integer -> Integer) -> Integer
foo = add . sub
```

**What I've understood :**

Haskell uses functions with only one args, so that we return a new function to execute after each function execution.

So the first `Integer` is the param type, while the second is the return type of a generated function that has to add the second number.

This will return another function (`sub`) that will makes the same flow (returning a function with params etc...)

Am I right ?

**Here's my actual error code :**

```
src\Main.hs:23:7:
    Couldn't match type `Integer' with `Integer -> Integer'
    Expected type: Integer -> (Integer -> Integer) -> Integer
      Actual type: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
    In the first argument of `(.)', namely `add'
    In the expression: add . sub

src\Main.hs:23:13:
    Couldn't match type `Integer -> Integer' with `Integer'
    Expected type: (Integer -> Integer) -> Integer
      Actual type: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
    Probable cause: `sub' is applied to too few arguments
    In the second argument of `(.)', namely `sub'
    In the expression: add . sub
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Can you help me understanding a bit more this error so I can find a solution ?

Comment: You're right in that it "doesn't make any sense" - there's no notion of composing binary functions in mathematics. If you want to make it make sense, you need to first define what "composing" addition and subtraction means.

Comment: Your type for foo says that the composition of addition and subtraction is a function that takes two *functions* (`Integer -> Integer`) and returns an integer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given a function

```
add :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
```

it's useful to remember (as you pointed out yourself in the *What I understood* section) that `->` in type signatures associates to the right, i.e. the above type is the same as

```
add :: Integer -> (Integer -> Integer)
```

Now, consider the type of `(.)`:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

This means that in an expression

```
(.) add
```

The `b` in the type of `(.)` is `Integer` and the `c` corresponds to `Integer -> Integer`. Another way to write this is

```
b ~ Integer
c ~ Integer -> Integer
```

So we get

```
(.) add :: (a -> Integer) -> a -> (Integer -> Integer)
```

If you now apply `(.) add` to `sub`, the compiler notices that `a -> Integer` cannot be made to match `Integer -> Integer -> Integer`.

I suspect that you probably want the composition to take *three* arguments: two to apply `sub` to, and the result of that is then - together with the third argument - passed to `add`. So a possible definition which composes the two functions would be

```
foo :: (Integer -> Integer -> Integer) -> (Integer -> Integer -> Integer) -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
foo f g x y = f (g x y) y
```

For what it's worth, there's a related problem: composing a two argument function with a one argument function, e.g. composing

Comment: A slightly different definition, `foo f g x y = f (g x y) y` can be shortened to `foo = liftM2 (.)`.

Answer (score 7):

> I want to be able to compose them. It doesn't make any sense okay, but it's for a learning aim.

That's actually the problem here. How do you want to compose them? Let us have a look at some possible compositions:

```
foo x y = sub x (add x y)          -- x + y - x = y
foo x y = sub y (add x y)          -- x + y - y = x
foo x y = sub x (add y y)          -- 2 * y - x 
foo x y = sub y (add y y)          -- 2 * y - y = y
foo x y = sub y (sub y (add x x))  -- 2 * x - 2 * y
```

That being said, let us inspect the type error by checking the types from hand:

```
type I = Integer -- otherwise the lines are going to be very long

(.)         :: (b ->    c   ) -> (a ->   b   ) -> a -> c
add         ::  I -> (I -> I)
sub         ::                   I -> (I -> I)
--                               |||||||||||||
(.) add     ::                   (a  -> I    ) -> a -> (I -> I)
--                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

As you can see, `(.) add` already mandates that the other function may only have type `a -> Integer` for an arbitrary `a`. But `sub`'s type is `Integer -> (Integer -> Integer)` (remember, `(->)` is right associative).

Now, what can you do to actually fix this? First, let us inspect your proposed type of `foo`:

```
foo :: (Integer -> Integer) -> (Integer -> Integer) -> Integer
```

That's actually a *very* interesting type of function. How would you actually get your result? You're just have two functions at hand, but no values:

```
> foo f g =
```

You can solve this by using a fixed point of one of the functions and then apply the other:

```
>   let x = f x in g x
>
> example = foo (const 12) (+1) -- returns 13
```

But that's not what you meant, right? At this point, it's very important to think about the semantics of  your composition. Since those are not clear, you cannot write a general way to compose both functions here.

However, if you *actually* meant

```
foo :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
foo x y z = add (sub x y) z
```

then that's possible with

```
foo = (add .) . sub
```

since

```
(.) add        :: (a -> I) -> a -> (I -> I)
(.) ((.) add)  :: (a -> b -> Integer) -> a -> b -> Integer -> Integer
```

But `(add .) . sub` isn't really easy to the eye anymore. You're better off writing a point-wise definition of `foo` if this kind of function was your original goal.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining `(add .) . sub` at the end of the answer! That was what I was searching for when I found this answer, not that I think that it would be a good idea to use in real code, just as a brain twister I was trying to figure out if it was even possible at all to make a ternary function out of a binary one without specifying parameters or using lambdas, but turns out it is and I really appreciate the beauty of it, even if I (currently at least) cannot really see a situation in which it would prove to be useful.